# Multivariable limit dilemma

Tags: limits

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\log(1-x^2y^2)}{x^2y^2}$

in polar coordinates:

$\lim\limits_{r \to 0} \frac{\log(1-r^2\cos^2t \sin^2t)}{r^2\cos^2t \sin^2t}$

The first limit exists if the second is independent from $t$. But if $t$ is $k \pi/2$ that fraction does not exist. So I could argue that the limit does not exist. Instead it is wrong the limit is $-1$. Where is the mistake?

**EDIT**

I know I can use another way to reach the result. My question is strictly related to this method (polar coordinates). Since the second limit does not exist for some $t$ I should think that the multivar limit does not exist. Perhaps are there some $t$ that I shouldn't care about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that: $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} = -1.$$
This can be checked with L'Hospital, for example. This will suffice because $x^2y^2 \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to {\bf 0}$ and both $x^2y^2$ and $\log(1-t)/t$ are continuous functions. The definition of limit ignores the value of the function at the point. This reasoning would be like saying that the limit of $f: \Bbb R \setminus\{0\}$ given by $f(x) = 1$ when $x \to 0$ does not exists because $f$ isn't defined there.

---

**Edit:** The value of $t$ is fixed, and you can't take $t = k\pi/2$ exactly because the function is not defined there. You only can take paths where the function is defined. For example, we have that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to{\bf 0}} \frac{xy}{y-x^3} = 0,$$ and you can't take the path $y = x^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, see the edit.

Comment: I added a little edit. :)

Comment: The key of it is in $$"\text{such that for all }t \in X,".$$

Comment: No, the limit is for $r \to 0$

Comment: OH! Sorry for the distraction. It is easier then. The value of $t$ is fixed, and you can't take $t = k\pi/2$ exactly because the function is not defined there. You only can take paths where the function is defined. For example, we have that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to{\bf 0}} \frac{xy}{y-x^3} = 0,$$ and you can't take the path $y = x^3$.

Comment: Edited. If you need anything more, please say.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use all that stuff: your expression is actually a function of the single variable $x^2y^2$, so the limit is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If we use Taylor series of $\ln(1-t)$ to get $\ln(1-t)\sim -t$ as $t\sim 0$ then the limit becomes easy to evaluate by observing that

$$ \frac{\ln(1-x^2 y^2)}{x^2y^2} \sim \frac{-x^2 y^2}{x^2y^2}= -1 $$

as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ .